# Town and out-of-town cheques: where are both payable?

Tags: canada, bank-account, check

In the [term database of the Government of Canada](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=1&index=alt&srchtxt=CHEQUE%20HORS%20PLACE), the definition is provided for an *out-of-town cheque*:

> A check [drawn] on a bank which is located outside the territory of
>   the clearing house with which the collecting bank is identified.

It is quite straightforward, but the French definition there is rather perplexing, as it states that "it is a cheque emitted in the city where the account is registered." I have read a number of sources in Italian and French (as I have been unable to find useful data in English), but all of them provide information similar to the one quoted from French above.

Could you please explain whether an 'out-of-town cheque' is a cheque drawn on a particular bank in a particular city (e.g. a bank in Toronto draws a check on a bank in Vancouver) or is it a cheque without the city mentioned (which means that it virtually becomes a 'town cheque' as I present it before a Toronto bank or an 'out-of town cheque' as I present it before a Vancouver bank)?

Comment: Since this could well be a translation issue (and you specifically mention the *perplexing* French definition), I suggest you quote that in your question as well.

Comment: *is it a cheque without the city mentioned* - that's not entirely possible, the "city" in this case is a property of the bank holding the account the check is drawn on. Even if the city isn't explicitly displayed on the physical check, it's basically determined by the collecting bank's clearinghouse when they process the check.

Comment: Wouldn't the definition be, "a cheque drawn on a bank without a branch in the town/city you are depositing the cheque"?

Comment: I've edited your post to remove the confusion. What French are you translating to get "emitted in the city where the account is registered"? I'm looking at this text which seems to correspond to the English fairly well:  "il existe deux types de chèques : ceux qui sont émis à l'intérieur de la ville où le compte est domicilié, désignés communément par «chèques sur place» et les autres, «chèques hors place», émis à l'extérieur de cette ville". My French isn't great but it seems to be roughly saying that "in-town cheques" come from the same town and "out-of-town cheques" come from outside.